# Angular Kendo-chart directive's tooltip is not hiding on iPad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using angular kendo-chart directive as below

```html
<div  id="chart" kendo-chart style="height: 100%"
       k-data-source="ctrl.myTrendSource"
       k-series="ctrl.chartOptions"
          k-legend="ctrl.legendOptions"
          k-value-axis="ctrl.valueAxisOptions"
          k-category-axis="ctrl.categoryAxisOptions"
          k-tooltip="ctrl.toolTipOptions"
          k-series-hover="ctrl.onSeriesHover"
          k-transitions="false">
     </div>
```

And in the controller, I have set up the chartOptions for k-series as below

```js
ctrl.chartOptions = [{
            type: 'line',
            field: 'score',
            name: 'My Performance',
            color: 'lightblue',
            markers: {
                type: 'rectangle',
                size: 8,
                border: 0,
                background: '#336699'
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: '${dataItem.label}<br/>${dataItem.volume_label}'
            },
            categoryField: 'date',
            render: ctrl.onRender
        }];
```

Tooltips are working fine on desktop (maybe because the event is bind to 'hover') and incase of iPad tooltips are not hiding even if we change the current view.

In case of iPad, we need to click on the points on the chart to see the tooltip. And then if I click somewhere on the chart then it hides as expected but if I change the url (angular state change like '/kendo-chart' to '/login'), it doesn't hide the tooltip. It persists on the page which is wrong.